# How to find if component is in external display in electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have created a reusable **component in react** to display a paragraph. I'm using the **same component in the external display.** Because the external display is bigger in size I want to apply large font on the component that's being mounted in the external display. Is there any **way to find if the component is mounted on the external display or not?**

To make it more clear, if the component is in external display I can add the condition to make the font larger in react. To do that I need to pass a prop to component that will hold the information if the component is being rendered on external display or not. Is there any way to do so? Or maybe any other solution that can help me achieve this output?

> Thank you in advance :)